# Multi Level Marketing SQL Query to calculate turnover of the team

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, mlm

I have a **users** table that looks someting like this :

```
ID NAME
1  Robin
2  Edward
3  Donald
4  Julie
```

The 2nd table **user_tree**

```
ID USER_ID TREE
1  1       ["2","3","4"]
2  2       ["3","4"]
3  3       ["4"]
4  4       []
```

The 3rd table **orders**

```
ID AMOUNT USER_ID
1  150    2
2  300    3
3  200    4
4  500    3
```

**the expected result, get the following table (create table mlm_team as select..) with a SQL query**

```
ID USER_ID TEAM_SUM
1  1       1150
2  2       1000
3  3       200
```

Is there an SQL expert who can help me?

Comment: How are you calculating the team sum in your expected result?

Comment: What kind of SQL have you tried, please?

Comment: What is the datatype of TREE? JSON?

Comment: TREE longtext
MySQL 5.7.9

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step:

```
- Create table and insert record.
- Get JSON type for array value
- Use "JSON_CONTAINS" for find MLM chain
```

Explain here:

```
create table users(id int, name varchar(50));
create table user_tree(id int, user_id int, tree json );
create table orders(id int, amount int, user_id int);

insert into users values(1,  'Robin');
insert into users values(2,  'Edward');
insert into users values(3 , 'Donald');
insert into users values(4 , 'Julie');

select * from users;

insert into user_tree values(1,  1 ,      '["2","3","4"]');
insert into user_tree values(2 , 2  ,     '["3","4"]');
insert into user_tree values(3 , 3  ,     '["4"]');
insert into user_tree values(4 , 4  ,     '[]');

select * from user_tree;

 insert into orders values(1 , 150  ,  2);
    insert into orders values(2 , 300  ,  3);
    insert into orders values(3 , 200  ,  4);
    insert into orders values(4 , 500 ,   3);

 select * from orders;
```

**- Final Query here:**

```
SELECT u1.id, u1.user_id as user_id, sum(amount)
FROM user_tree u1
left outer join user_tree u2 on JSON_CONTAINS(u1.tree, concat('["', u2.user_id ,'"]'))
left outer join orders o1 on o1.user_id = u2.user_id
where u2.user_id
group by u1.id, u1.user_id
order by u1.id;
```

Find SQL Fiddle details from here [LINK](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b93nujm9hGzpBiChZDx5Vh/0).